# How to find "cost function" given Cobb-Douglas production function as well as per-unit and fixed costs?

Tags: proof-verification, lagrange-multiplier, economics

I'm working on the following homework problem, transcribed verbatim:

> A firm has a production function defined as $y = 8L^{1/4}K^{3/4}$. The firm faces costs of \$20 wage, \$60 rental rate of capital, \$2 per unit produced, and a \$42 fixed cost. Find the cost function, and average total cost, average variable cost, and marginal cost functions.

I'm confused on two levels.

(1) Does "cost function" mean *short-term* cost function, holding capital constant, or does it mean *long-term* cost function, allowing both inputs to vary? How can the professor possibly be so clueless as to fail to realize that the question is ambiguous as written?

(2) If the firm faces costs of "\$2 per unit produced and a \$42 fixed cost," shouldn't the cost function simply be $c(y)=2y+42$? But this answer contradicts the solution I get when I use the Lagrangian approach.

According to the minimization problem, the cost function $c(y)$ is the minimum value of $20L+60K$ subject to the constraint that $y=8L^{1/4}K^{3/4}$. The Lagrangian condition says

$$20=2\lambda (K/L)^{3/4}$$
$$60=6\lambda(L/K)^{1/4}$$

so

$$10(L/K)^{3/4}=10(K/L)^{1/4} \implies L=K$$

Therefore $y=8K$ and thus the cost function is $c(y)=80K=10y$. This is not the same thing as $c(y)=2y+42$. What is going on here?

Comment: I have the same result like yours: $C(y)=10y$. I can´t imagine what is meant by "$\$2$ per unit produced and a $\$42$ fixed cost," in this context.

Comment: I think you use the production function to find out how much labor and capital cost you, but then for the full cost function you have to add in the fixed cost and the variable cost that doesn't come from labor or capital.